# Get field from selected CursorLoader

Tags: android, cursor, android-cursorloader

Ive just changed my code to use CursorLoader as opposed to the depreciated manageCursor() methods.

But have no idea how to get fields from the cursor at current clicked position

```
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    return new SQLiteCursorLoader(getActivity(), new DatabaseHelper(getActivity()), "SELECT M.id as _id,  M.name as desc FROM myTable M", null);    
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        // before I did, 
        // cursor.moveTo(position);
        // cursor.getInt(1);
        // WHat goes here?
```

Surely I dont have to take the id and requery what the cursor already contains.
That would defeat some of the point of this managed concept.

There must be a way to access the fields at a given position.

Comment: what's your sqlitecursorloader ?

Comment: also, getInt(1) seems strange, considering 1 is the name column in your case.

Comment: @njzk2 I just put that in as quick example. since it was commented out anyway. There are many other fields. sqlitecursorLoader is Commonwares extension to the Cursorloader class for sqlite Databases. It does the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way of doing this is to use

```
l.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

This is a Cursor, because your adapter is a CursorAdapter (right?), so you can do :

```
Cursor cursor = (Cursor) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

and you don't even need to moveToPosition() thing.

This is equivalent to `l.getAdapter().getItem(position)`, which is a Cursor positioned at position. You could also have a reference to the Adapter and call

```
mCursorAdapter.getCursor();
```

Comment: Looks good to me. Will test it out tomorrow thanks! I knew it should be straight forward, I just couldn't seem to find the API. This is much neater. And theres no scope that cursor is blank.

Comment: Is there something similar to get the item cursor from `public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)`?

Comment: i would assume context menu is displayed on selected item, therefore listView.getSelectedItem() should work.